# How to make a "flyout" control without affecting other controls in menu

Tags: wpf

Alright, here comes something tricky and I really hope there's some WPF guru here who knows a solution or at least a good approach for it:

I got a menu which can be switched into compact mode. In this mode only the label color, the icon and some informational controls are visible. All content of the menu item is hidden.

Now *Normal* and *Compact* modes are nice, but not very smooth. In compact mode the whole menu expands when you move your mouse over it. I'd like to achieve this effect with just one single menu item, but without resizing the whole menu (since the menu has a different background than the rest of the window, it would be visible that the whole menu expanded but not all menu items).

My idea is a "flyout". This alone might not be too difficult to implement, but there's some criteria which should be met in order to make it look good.

Here are pictures of the compact menu and one item in it's normal state.

[image: Compact Menu]
[image: Normal-State Menu Item]

Now I'd like to achieve that when you move over one of the compact entries, the entry kinda flies out to the left and is visible in it's full state like a popup. The problem here is: I can't remove the control since this would alter the menu order (visibly). I can't use a *VisualBrush* since it needs to be interactive.

As you can see, this looks pretty ugly.

[image]

That is what I would like to achieve (just poorly pasted in):

[image]

Any ideas how you could implement this?

Comment: Does "not affecting other controls in menu" not include displacement of menu items because of the larger size of the "normal" menu item that flies out? I only ask because that's what your last screenshot suggests is happening. Also, what kind of control are you using to set up your menu?

Comment: Yeah. The second last image shows how it looks if I just switch one item to normal state - it takes full size and thus all adjust to that size - which should not happen. Only the selected one should fly out. I'm currently using a custom styled ItemsControl.

Comment: Popup control, same as a submenu. Each item has a Content (goes in the polyp) and a CompactContent. Look at a menu template for stuff to steal.

Comment: Thank you guys, works like a charm! For anyone who is trying the same: On entering any element I create a clone with equal properties, remove and insert the content elements (which can exist only one in the logical tree) into the copy. I monitor mouse events when moved outside the popup I copy them back to the original menu entry and close the popup. The popup is element of the menu, thus you need to translate with the selected element's position to position the popup next to it. Thanks guys!